# How to sum of two rows values inside the datagridview c#

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

How to sum of two rows values inside the DataGridView, if the id of the both rows same and create one rows instead of two rows in the DataGrid?

Like the following example:

```
id           quantity       Bonus        price           total

01             25           10           123            4305

01             5             10          123            1845


I want to sum of the above two rows like this in the DataGrid.


id           quantity        Bonus         price          total

01              30            20             246          6150
```

if i take loop on it then duplicate value insert in the datagridview.

Comment: If the ID of both records is the same, how are you going to fetch your data in the first place?

Comment: @vanitha may i know how you are filling `grid` if possible post the code

Comment: is the data from database? if yes, you should have group and sum it before populate to the grid. and show us some code

Answer (score 0):

consider 'grid' is the name of your grid:

```
dim a(3) as integer
for i as integer =0 to grid.rows.count-1
for j as integer =0 to 3
a(j)=a(j)+ cint(grid.rows(i).cells(j).value)
next
next
grid.rows.add("Total",a(0),a(1),a(2),a(3)) ' will add a row at the end of last row
```